# scrartcl: Set footnote marker outside the mark width box

Tags: footnotes, koma-script

In the [`scrartcl`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrartcl) package, the `\deffootnote` command is used to adjust the typesetting of footnotes:

```
\deffootnote[<mark width>]{<indent>}{<parindent>}{<definition>}
```

… which affects the footnote layout like so:

[image: KOMA-Script user guide]

As the user guide explains, "[t]he mark in the footnote is
type-set right-aligned in a box with width `mark width`."

What I'm trying to do is set the footnote mark *just beyond* the right edge of that box, so that the mark begins consistently with the value for `parindent`. In other words, rather than this:

```
---
  1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
     Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget,
consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
...
 10. Nunc hendrerit lobortis diam et tristique. Duis ante tellus,
lobortis eu sodales sed, sollicitudin et enim.
```

I want to output this:

```
---
     1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
     Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget,
consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
...
     10. Nunc hendrerit lobortis diam et tristique. Duis ante tellus,
lobortis eu sodales sed, sollicitudin et enim.
```

Part of the difficulty is that I need to be able to handle `footnotemark`s of different lengths (1, 2, 3, ... 11, 12, 13, ... 101, 102, 103). Anyone know how I might be able to do that using `KOMA-Script`?

Answer (score 2):

The correct definition of `\deffootnote` is

```
\deffootnote[<mark width>]{<indent>}{<parindent>}{<definition>}
```

(Note that the indent is set in the argument *before* parindent.)

You have to decide how much space is needed for the footnotenumbers. I will use `1.5em` in the following example

```
\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnote.}
```

Then you can use

```
\deffootnote
 [<indent+parindent+1.5em>]
 {<indent>}
 {<parindent>}
 {\hspace*{<indent+parindent>}\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnote.}
```

to get the desired output.

Example with an indent of `0em` and a parindent of `1em`:

```
\deffootnote[2.5em]{0em}{1em}{\hspace*{1em}\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnote.}
```

[image]

Or with an indent of `1.5em` and a parindent of `1em`:

```
\deffootnote[4em]{1.5em}{1em}{\hspace*{2.5em}\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark.}}
```

[image]